# Modifying a Chrome Extension broke the extension

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have the rikaikun japanese translator and i made changes to the css folder, it runs good but after 2 seconds it tells me that the extension could be broken. How can i keep these simple css changes without breaking the extension? (I Modified the color values on the css file)

Answer (score 0):

I copied the contents of the extension and loaded it again to chrome on development mode, now it doesn't crash.